# How can I get status information (e.g., 7/30 uploaded) when publishing using ClickOnce?

Tags: c#, clickonce

It really irks me to sit around waiting for "Publishing files..." to finish.  I am publishing using FTP, so maybe this is the issue.

Here's what the output looks like:

```
Connecting to 'ftp://example.com/public_html/download/xxx/'...
Publishing files...
Publish success.
http://example.com/download/xxx/publish.htm
========== Build: 12 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

In between "..." and "Publish success" is a rather long wait for which I would like a more detailed status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to enumerate those files as they are published for a client application. I think it does it for a VSTO app, but not for a regular client application.

I'll turn this into the PM at MSFT again as a frequently requested item.

Answer (score 1):

If you're publishing from Visual Studio, simply show the Output Window and pay attention to it during a publishing process. (Go to View->Output to view the Output window.)

The Output window displays build info, errors and the status of the ClickOnce publication process.  When you publish your application, ClickOnce has to generate a few files and then it publishes all of the associated file with your project.  When it is copying your files to the publication server, each file that has been updated is enumerated in the Output window, complete with a *x* of *n* count.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmmm... On the projects Publish tab, open the Options... dialog.  From the Publish Options dialog, click on deployment.  Is 'Verify files uploaded to a web server' checked?  If not, you may want to check it and see if that changes it.  The verification check may significantly lengthen the time it takes for the application to publish because it test the upload by immediately downloading the file after it's been uploaded.  (See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z83t16a.aspx)

Comment: Ok, checked and trying... whoa, immediately downloads it?  I can't check that.

Comment: I bit the bullet and checked it, however, it only verifies it AFTER the upload has been completed, so we are still not truly getting status as the files are being uploaded.